# Make an even spaces to my columns using flexbox using space between

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Hi guys how can I achieve spaces on my three columns? I already use space-between but it doesn't change anything, but I tried to use margin-top and the result is not what I want.

```css
.weather {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  &__title {
    flex: 33%;
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
  &__input {
    flex: 33%;
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
  &__details {
    flex: 33%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.7);
  }
}
```

```html
<section className="weather">
  <div className="weather__background" />

  <div className="weather__title">
    <h1>React Weather</h1>
  </div>

  <div className="weather__input">
    <h1>React Weather</h1>
    <input onChange={getLocation} required autoFocus placeholder="Enter a Country..." />
  </div>

  <div className="weather__details">

    <h1>React Weather</h1>
  </div>



</section>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make them take up the full height of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need to fix the space-between of divs inside the weather tag or weather__background tag. Note that flex-box need to have a parent > child direct relationship, for example, you used the `flex-direction: column;` on the div.weather tag but the next child of this tag is the div.weather__background.
To flex-box works you have to use the flex-direction or on the `weather__background` or remove this tag and use directly on the `.weather` div.

I don't know if this code can help you:

```css
.weather__background {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between; }
  .weather__background > * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 15px; }
    .weather__background > *:hover {
      background-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.7); }

.weather__input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center; }
  .weather__input input {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 3px; }
```

```html
<section class="weather">
  <div class="weather__background" />

    <div class="weather__title">
      <h1>React Weather</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="weather__input">
      <h1>React Weather:</h1>
      <input onChange={getLocation} required autoFocus placeholder="Enter a Country..." />
    </div>

    <div class="weather__details">

    <h1>React Weather</h1>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

If you need the SCSS version of style (the code snippet will not run I think):

```css
.weather {
  
  &__background{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
    > * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      &:hover{
        background-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.7);
      }
    }
  }

  
  &__input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    input {
      margin-left: 10px;
      padding: 3px;
    }
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<section class="weather">
  <div class="weather__background" />

    <div class="weather__title">
      <h1>React Weather</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="weather__input">
      <h1>React Weather:</h1>
      <input onChange={getLocation} required autoFocus placeholder="Enter a Country..." />
    </div>

    <div class="weather__details">

    <h1>React Weather</h1>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

Usually, the usage of space-between works well when you have a fixed dimension on your parent container and you can see the child elements fixing inside your container but when you have variable dimensions the child elements will fix inside de content and probably you will not see the effect happening.
You can try to put 1000px of height on .weather__background to see the difference.

I hope it helps you =)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your items take up the full height, add this to your CSS:

```css
html {
   height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

You can remove the `flex: 33%` from each class

```css
.weather {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    &__title {
      border: 3px solid red;
    }
    &__input {
      border: 3px solid red;
    }
    &__details {
      border: 3px solid red;
      background-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.7);
    }
}
```